# Leiningen: How to define constants in project.clj?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have some values repeated in my `project.clj` like below:

```lisp
(defproject foo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ...

  :dependencies [[bar "3.4.5"]
                 [baz "3.4.5"]
                 [bat "3.4.5"]]

  ...)
```

I would like to use some sort of constant here so, when these libraries get updated to `3.5.0` for example, I have to change just one place.

What is the best practise here? Best I can come up with is this:

```lisp
(def deps-version "3.4.5")

(defproject foo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ...

  :dependencies [[bar ~deps-version]
                 [baz ~deps-version]
                 [bat ~deps-version]]

  ...)
```

Comment: I added an answer but thought you were unable to get the constants to work, is this the case? You're missing the `~` char in your example, i.e. `[bar ~deps-version]`. Your own solution is something I've used outside of leiningen (in gradle for selenium driver versions) so there's only one change to make, and fits well enough.

Comment: so what's the essence of your question now? if it's just "should I use versions like this?" then answer's probably simply, yes.

Comment: @MarkFisher, muhuk is asking what the best practice is.  You have stated what you believe the best practice is, so you could offer it as an Answer.

Comment: which seems a little subjective to me as a 'question'

Comment: @MarkFisher you are right, I probably didn't phrase my question right. But I was wondering if there were other, better ways. To give a somewhat contrived example, you can do `#=(eval (...))` and read constants from a file. (Which is perhaps not too absurd since you can make this file a resource and read it within the app too.) Feel free to edit the question BTW, the gist is `how to define constants`.

Answer (score 6):

Using a definition before `defproject` is totally fine and common practice.

You can also so more advanced stuff like depending on the build environment (I would tag the effective project version too that case). A nice example is found in the answers to this question "[Leiningen: How to define constants in project.clj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114818/leiningen-how-to-define-constants-in-project-clj)"

Comment: The link, uh, leads to this same page. To understand recursion one must understand recursion...